# Extract Wavelength from MP3 as an Image

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, lame

Are there any good libraries that can help convert an MP3 into an image of its wavelengths (I think that's the proper term). What I'm looking for is a way to generate the wavelengths of MP3s server-side like is done on Souncloud: http://soundcloud.com/smixx/takin-vc-money-money-cash-ipos

What would be the best approach to extact that type of image from an audio file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the best response from the community:
http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/

The correct term is **WAVEFORM** that's what you see @soundcloud. 
From what I've seen, the PHP script is pretty lightweight and awesome!

BTW: I just realized that the stackoverflow question points to the same PHP code @andrewfreiday

EDIT: Just a FYI, I started playing with node.js for a while now and while I was making a simple MP3 player I started using this packaged for the waveform.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/waveform-data

Comment: Is there a C# version of this PHP script?

Comment: Andrew Freiday's website appears to be dead right now.